# how to get location provider (GPS or Network) time in android

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I've tried getTime() method from Location class to get the time when the fix is obtained. But it does not give the time from location-provider moreover this time can be modified by setTime() method from same class. Can we get time from location-providers (irrespective of timezones) which is more accurate and robust ?

Comment: "But it does not give the time from location-provider" What does it give you? "moreover this time can be modified by setTime() method from same class." Every field in Location has a set method, including latitude and longitude...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sam.
I am looking for a timestamp from location-provider, the same time when location details were sent which cannot be modified the user. any info on that ?

Comment: do we've any other source for time at all ??

Comment: You can always create your own timestamp, `long time = System.currentTimeMillis()`. `onLocationChanged()` is typically called within a few milliseconds of when the Location object is created, if you create your own timestamp here it will be roughly as accurate as `getTime()`.